# Where do i start with using RESTful API's?

Tags: javascript, api, httprequest

I understand that the idea is to create basic HTTP Requests using GET or POST. 
I'm fluent with working in HTML, CSS and a little Javascript. But I've never 
touched Ajax or anything to do with HTTP Requests. I understand that Ajax is for dynamic page content, and can be used to call other servers but that requires creating your own Ajax stubs. 
Anyway I want to know the best way to go about making HTTP Request ultimately i want call using the KAYAK API and the functions they provide to search flights, but theres a whole session system involved which confuses me even more.

What would you suggest I start with I'm not really a coder (other than HTTP and CSS), and I don't really want to get into learning a whole new language for the purpose of one project so please keep the suggestion simple, maybe using just Javascript.

Also any suggestions on things to read, when it comes to HTTP Requests... not what they are... more how to impliment them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid there is no silver bullet...

In the end you have to choose a programming language, learn it and understand what HTTP requests are and how to make them. Eventually you also want to do something with that data once you have retrieved it and for that you need to learn a programming language anyway.

Note that talking to a RESTful API is in fact not necessarily related to AJAX (and therefore Javascript). That is the point of offering such an API. You can communicate with a RESTful API with any programming language capable of making HTTP requests. There are a lot of desktop applications and mobile apps which do this as well.

So if you are serious about writing a professional piece of software, my recommendation would be to choose a programming language, pick up a beginner book on that language and start working through it. You might get away with reading forums and newsgroups for a while, but in the end you will probably be better off learning it if you start programming in more structured way from the very beginning.

Comment: Thanks for the strait forward answer, It's nice just to get a strait answer for once. The problem is its of a university project, we havent been geven any guidance in any programming languages, its not good at all! yet were expected to produced polished prototype software. Guess i'm going to have to really go crazy learning some sort of language. cheers.